# Change RabbitMQ Consumer Callback to Invoke with 1 Argument (body) Instead of 4 Arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

Normally, by `pika` driver, when we set a consumer, we should pass a callback as parameter. On new message, pika will invoke the callback with 4 arguments: `ch, method, property, body`.

I need my callback to get just one argument: `body`.

I mean:

```
def my_callback(body):
    pass
```

Instead of:

```
def my_callback(ch, method, property, body):
    pass
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: Can't you just `lambda ch, method, property, body: my_callback(body)`?

Comment: @jdehesa, thank you so much! it works! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jdehesa said, the solution is using `lambda` expression, like so:

```
lambda ch, method, property, body: my_callback(body)
```